# Compare dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary

As part of a wider project (to learn) I am building a script to discover discovering the files recursively in a folder.  Then adding the filename (including the path) and the size in bytes to a CSV file.

I've then loaded that CSV file as a python dictionary.

What I would like to do now, is have python parse over each value in the dictionary (which is the size) and compare it to all others in the dictionary.  If it finds a match, I want it to show me which keys (file name) have the matching values.  I'll then do an MD5 hash on those that appear to have the same size.

The code below is as far as I've got - can anyone assist please?

```py
    #!/usr/bin/env python3

    import argparse
    import os
    import sys
    import csv
    import fnmatch

    def verify_args():
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Compare files recursively.')
        parser.add_argument('path', help='Location to begin file comparison from.')
        check = parser.parse_args()

        if os.path.isdir(check.path):
            print(check.path,'is a valid path - continuing' + '\n')
        else:
            print(check.path,'is an invalid path - exiting' + '\n')
            sys.exit()
        return parser.parse_args()

    def listfiles(file_path):
        print ('Starting comparison')
        pattern = '*'
        with open('/tmp/foo','w') as fo:
            fo.write('file,size' + '\n')
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(file_path):
                for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
                    fo.write(os.path.join(root, filename) + ',' + str(os.path.getsize(os.path.join(root, filename))) + '\n')
        files = {}

        with open('/tmp/foo') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
                files[row['file']] = row['size']
            x = files.keys()
            print(x)
            # Not sure now what to do

    def main():
        args = verify_args()
        file_path = args.path
        listfiles(file_path) 



    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: What's the problem here? You say you want to loop over the values of the dictionary and, for each value, compare it to all other values of said dictionary. Is there a problem with this?

Comment: All the examples I've seen so far compare two dictionaries against each other - i want to compare just within the one dictionary.  So things like cmp cannot help me.

Comment: Do you know how to loop over the values (or items) of a dictionary? If you want to "parse over each value in the dictionary and compare it to all others in the dictionary", you'll need to loop over each value of the dictionary, and for each such value you loop over the same dictionary again to compare this value to others. What's the problem here?

Comment: No i do not know how to parse over each value in the dictionary or how I would compare it to the others.  Can you give me a pointer please?

Comment: @user2312666 What you really need to do is build a dictionary of lists, where the keys are the file sizes and the lists contain all the files of a given size. Then there's no need to search the dictionary at all. To do this, use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict): i.e. `from collections import defaultdict` ... `files = defaultdict(list)` and then `files[row['size']].append(row['file'])`.

Comment: @user2312666, please read [the docs on `dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

Comment: @ekhumoro - That makes sense.  I can understand how that helps.  Thank you.  Will give it a try.

Comment: @ekhumoro - Thanks so much for this.  I've got it working as its then doing a len on the number of values.  If a size has more than one file name i am now passing it on to the next function.  Thank you :)